# Windows Ce Device does not deploy "The bootstrap could not be loaded."

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-ce

I am trying to have some time to deploy my application with a motorola device MC32N0 before was with the MC3190 smoothly.

[image]

The error that occurs after shows me have performed the deployment is this:

[image]
"The bootstrap could not be loaded."

OS my computer is Windows 8.1.
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.
The device operating system is Microsoft Windows Embedded Version 7.00.

I checked issues as is the Stackoverflow, made a series of steps to try to solve the problem.

- I realized the installation of EMDK to try to solve the problem.
  (EMDK FOR .NET - WINDOWS CE 7)
  found this link:
  https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-net.html
  (installed version 2.9 (last available))
- I have already read chapter 10 of the guide (Application Deployment for Windows CE) the MC3200 INTEGRATOR GUIDE, which can be seen at the link below, and no success in solving the problem:

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/mc3200-integrator-guide-en-us.pdf

Someone has performed these steps and went through this situation? Thank you very much in advance.

One detail is that it also does not connect to the device mobile center, with the 3190 model I could to deploy also not connected, which shows me the device center mobile is an exception "System.UnauthorizedAccessException," I have done reinstallation thereof, migrated to the latest version 6.1, and permenece with the same error. (The also ran as an administrator, but without success)

Comment: Your first trial to connect and deploy was with ActiveSync? Would be ActiveSync a good choice for you?